# Compare two MySQL dump files

Tags: mysql, backup, schema, mysqldump

I am trying to compare two MySQL dump files. One was made from a fresh install of a web application and the other is a dump from the same web application that has been upgraded from a previous version to the same version number as the fresh install.

Basically I want to make sure that the upgrade scripts worked properly and all the proper columns and constraints are in the upgraded version just as they are in fresh install. I thought a simple diff/sdiff would be good enough for this but I ran into the problem with that: Column order.

The column order between the fresh install and the upgrade are different giving many false positive "differences". It is easy to see when looking at the output that the same column is simply in a different spot but with hundreds of tables it would take a long time to check and identify these false positives.

Is there a better way to compare these two dumps that will ignore column order (or a way to force the dumps to have columns in alphabetical order or something similar) or an entirely different approach that would work better. I am admittedly fairly new to MySQL and am just learning as I go so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the mysqldumps already loaded in two different MySQL Instances ???

Comment: One of the dumps, the fresh install dump,  i have made and will give to the person doing the upgrade of the customer system. My hope is that they can do teh upgrade of the system and then compare it to the dump i have provided them from a fresh install which is a 'known good' schema.

So they will have access to one of the database as it is running in the server they are upgrade but the other one will be just a dump file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot force the ordering of columns in a mysqldump. You can, however, use the table [**`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html). You will need the following:

- MySQL Instance with the old data loaded
- MySQL Instance with the new data loaded
- Some Patience and Scripting

With this setup in mind, here is what you need to do:

## STEP 01) Use Query to Present Columns Ordered Per Database/Table

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name),
GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY column_name)
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema NOT IN
('information_schema','performance_schema')
GROUP BY table_schema,table_name;
```

This will give you every table followed by a CSV list of alphabetically-sorted columns

## STEP 02) Launch this Column Query From Both MySQL Instances

```
IPADDR_OLD=10.1.20.30
IPADDR_NEW=10.1.20.40
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name),"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY column_name)"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema NOT IN"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} ('information_schema','performance_schema')"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} GROUP BY table_schema,table_name"
mysql -u... -p... -h${IPADDR_OLD} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"  > column_listing1.txt
mysql -u... -p... -h${IPADDR_NEW} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" >> column_listing2.txt
cat column_listing1.txt  > column_listing.txt
cat column_listing2.txt >> column_listing.txt
```

Run the Column Query and Collect the Results in `column_listing.txt`

## STEP 03) Perform Unique Sort ; Check For Duplicate Table Names

```
sort -u < column_listing.txt > column_listing.unq
UNQ_LINES=`wc -l < column_listing.unq`
TXT_LINES=`wc -l < column_listing.txt`
(( DIF_LINES = (UNQ_LINES + UNQ_LINES - TXT_LINES) / 2))
echo ${DIF_LINES}
```

If everything is identical, `DIF_LINES` should 0. Otherwise, there are duplicates present.

## STEP 04) If There Are Duplicates, Find Them

```
diff column_listing1.txt column_listing2.txt
```

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-03-22 13:04 EDT

You can also check other metadata tables such as

## TABLE_CONSTRAINTS

```
mysql> desc TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | varchar(512) | NO   |     |         |       |
| CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| CONSTRAINT_NAME    | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_SCHEMA       | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_NAME         | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| CONSTRAINT_TYPE    | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## STATISTICS

```
mysql> desc STATISTICS;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | varchar(512)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_SCHEMA  | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_NAME    | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| NON_UNIQUE    | bigint(1)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| INDEX_SCHEMA  | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| INDEX_NAME    | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| SEQ_IN_INDEX  | bigint(2)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| COLUMN_NAME   | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| COLLATION     | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CARDINALITY   | bigint(21)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SUB_PART      | bigint(3)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PACKED        | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NULLABLE      | varchar(3)    | NO   |     |         |       |
| INDEX_TYPE    | varchar(16)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| COMMENT       | varchar(16)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| INDEX_COMMENT | varchar(1024) | NO   |     |         |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS

```
mysql> desc REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS;
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG        | varchar(512) | NO   |     |         |       |
| CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA         | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| CONSTRAINT_NAME           | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | varchar(512) | NO   |     |         |       |
| UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME    | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MATCH_OPTION              | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| UPDATE_RULE               | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| DELETE_RULE               | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_NAME                | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME     | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Setup queries that perform the same styled comparison

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try now. Any thoughts on how to check and make sure the constraints are also the same between the two?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to first create a temporary database from the old dump you could use a different tool, which can create dumps that are nice to compare:

It is called `pydumpy` https://code.google.com/p/pydumpy/ written by https://github.com/z1lv1n4s 
(github mirror: https://github.com/miebach/pydumpy)